# User "system:anonymous" cannot proxy services in the namespace "kube-system".: "No policy matched.\nUnknown user \"system:anonymous\""

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am getting the following error when trying to access the Kubernetes dashboard found in the cluster info:

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

Also pops up in incognito mode in Chrome:

> User "system:anonymous" cannot proxy services in the namespace "kube-system".: "No policy matched.\nUnknown user \"system:anonymous\""

Comment: How are you authenticating? The error message printing `system:anonymous` makes it look like you aren't providing any client credentials and are being rejected by the RBAC configuration in your cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to access it with a local proxy by running:

```
kubectl proxy
```

And then navigating to http://127.0.0.1:8001/ui (http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/proxy/#!/workload?namespace=default).

Might be related to an upgrade to version 1.6.